# Is there a concise way to return the numerical iterator in a loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, for-loop, conditional-statements

It seems like there should be a **one-liner** way to iterate over `season` and return the last `season` when `show.has_season?` evaluates to `false`.

```
def last_season(show)
  season = 1
  season += 1 while show.has_season?(season)
  return season
end
```

Edit:  `has_season?` involves an HTTP GET call, so I can't really see a clean way around iterating using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use something like this:

```
def last_season(show)
  (1..1.0/0.0).find {|season| not show.has_season?(season)|
end
```

But I feel that the class representing `show` should provide that `last_season` method and there is likely to be a way to compute it without having to bruteforce through possible numbers of seasons.

Comment: In case it's not known, 1.0/0.0 returns positive Infinity. Beginning with Ruby 1.9.2, you could also use Float::INFINITY instead

Comment: Thanks, yes the implementation should be in the `Show` class, but I still would need the loop.

Answer (score 5):

What you're doing is sort of a roundabout way of getting to an answer. What is the `has_season?` method doing? Would it make sense for your show object to have an array of seasons? Then you could just do something like:

```
class Show
  attr_accessor :seasons

  def initialize
    @seasons = []
  end

  def last_season
    seasons.last
  end
end

show = Show.new
show.seasons = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
show.last_season # => 6
```

Comment: `has_season?` involves an HTTP GET and parsing the HTML, so I can't really see a clean way around iterating.  Maybe there is a better way...?

Comment: Is there no overview page that tells you how many seasons exist for a given show? Most websites I know do. That'd definitely be easier on the server than requesting the season information for every season as well.

Comment: Ok that changes things. I still think you should move the last_season logic to the show method, but it's really hard to say how you should be refactoring it without knowing more about your class.

Comment: There are some pages like that, but its easier to parse search results for each season, unless you know a website with an easily parsable season/episode list.  Although this is kind of tangential to the question itself.

Comment: thetvdb.com has season/episode lists and it seems easy enough to parse for XBMC to use and maintain it as one of the primary scrapers. Here's an example for House, MD: http://thetvdb.com/?tab=series&id=73255&lid=7

Answer (score 0):

In order for a show to respond to `has_season?` it must already know its own seasons.

The `last_season?` method should be part of the `Show` class. A `Show` would have either an enumeration or a `max_season`-like value, and it should just return the highest value or the max season.